# Using MetroLog in C# to direct the logs into a specified File Location

Tags: c#, windows, logging, uwp, metrolog

Similar to java.util.logging package, I am trying to use MetroLog in C# implementation of Logging. From the [documentation](https://github.com/onovotny/MetroLog/wiki/FileStreamingTarget) of MetroLog, I am unable to find an example for the same.

My snippet

```
var naming = new FileNamingParameters()
                    {
                        IncludeLevel = false,
                        IncludeLogger = false,
                        IncludeSequence = false,
                        IncludeSession = false,
                        IncludeTimestamp = FileTimestampMode.None
                    };

var info = GetLogEventInfo();
var filename = naming.GetFilename(new LogWriteContext(), info);
```

Is there any way I can set my filename programmatically ?

The documentation shows the way to use the Default logging location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot dynamically set the File name using Metro logs, the only thing you can do is set `FileNamingParameters.FileTimestampMode` to either `Date` (for creating a file for each day) or `DateTime` for the filename containing Date and time both.

If you want your own file names then use the [open sourced version](https://github.com/onovotny/MetroLog) of the library and then change the logic for naming the file in the following method - `GetOrCreateStreamWriterForFile` in the `FileTargetBase.cs`

Comment: Could you plz give an example of how to set this FileNamingParameters.FileTimestampMode with code.